# Wordpress read more does not show up the rest of the post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have placed a read more element in my post and while the read more appears on my page when I click it, it does not display the rest of the post.

```
<?php
  global $more;
  $more = 0;
?>

<div id="content">

<?php
  query_posts('cat=5');
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'full', true);
    echo '<div class="myContent">
    <img class="image" src="'.$thumb_url[0].'" >';

    the_content('<div class="read">READ MORE</div>');
    echo'</div>';
  endwhile;
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no link pointing.
it should be like this maybe:

```
<?php
  global $more;
  $more = 0;
?>

<div id="content">

<?php
  query_posts('cat=5');
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'full', true);
    echo '<div class="myContent">
    <img class="image" src="'.$thumb_url[0].'" >';

    the_content('<div class="read"><a href="<?php the_permalink ?>">READ MORE</a></div>');
    echo'</div>';
  endwhile;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the case the url changes but the remaining post does not show up.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you are using a custom theme, maybe providing also an example, and from what you have said this seems to be the single.php page right?

Comment: Yes I am developing a theme and this is a custom template page. It is not single.php